# How do I change the PAGER variable for man if it's possible?

Tags: man, pager

I'm not an expert in Linux, but I was reading an introductory book and found that `man` pages use the `PAGER` environment variable to show the content of `man` pages. I checked `printenv` and didn't find any `PAGER` variable there.

However, since it's a binary, and the path to `/usr/bin` is in my path, there is a program called `pager` in Linux as well, and I think it's what is the default option for `$PAGER`.

Just out of curiosity I would like to know how to modify this `PAGER` variable. I tried adding one to my bashfile but that didn't work, couldn't find how pager can be changed.

And whats so special about pager - I expect any program that can read from `stdin`, or support piping stuff, can be pager, can `vim` be a pager?

Internally it seems the `man` just uses `sed` to send data to a defined `PAGER` variable because doing following works, but fails.

```
env PAGER=/usr/bin/nano man printf
```

and I get an error, like following

[image]

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16740246/what-is-a-way-to-read-man-pages-in-vim-without-using-temporary-files

Comment: The issue with a pager is that it needs to accept input piped to it from the process that generates the text, and also take your editor-type commands from the terminal (also on stdin). I don't know the detail of how that is done. However, your problem with `nano` is that it has no file to edit, but is getting the whole of the man page on stdin and attempting to treat it as editor commands. The junk you see is a consequence of `nano` changing the terminal modes to suit its use of the `ncurses` package.

Comment: It's probably not wise to assume that a command is the default for something just because it's name something. But I have no idea what the 'pager` command on your system does, I don't have one on my system, and don't think I've ever seen one.

Comment: In general editors (such as `vim` and `nano` that you mention are meant to edit things, and man pages are not meant to be edited, so editors are probably bad choices in general. Here you'll additionally run into the problem that processing the man page outputs formatting characters that most editors just display as-is. `vim` (I don't have `nano` installed so I can't try that) will also warn that input is not from a terminal, which leads to another defining characteristic, a pager must be able to handle two input streams, one for the data and one for your commands.

Answer (score 3):

The `PAGER` variable isn't only used for `man`, but for any other output that needs to be paged, such as `git branch`, `journalctl`, etc.

If you want this setting to be applied only for manpages, you should use `MANPAGER` instead.

**To define `vim` as the `MANPAGER`:**

```bash
export MANPAGER="vim +MANPAGER -"
```

- `+MANPAGER` puts `vim` into *manpage* mode (colors, hide unvisible characters, etc.). This will also make it read-only
- The `-` at the end indicates to read text from standard input (*stdin*)

**For other pagers:**

- Nano (won't be pretty as explained by @muru):

  ```bash
  export MANPAGER="nano -"
  ```

For the following you don't need to add the hyphen because these programs are originally desinged to read from *stdin*.

- Most:

  ```bash
  export MANPAGER="most"
  ```
- Less:

  ```bash
  export MANPAGER="less"
  ```
- More:

  ```bash
  export MANPAGER="more"
  ```
- [Bat](https://github.com/sharkdp/bat) (nice colors and formatting):

  ```bash
  export MANPAGER="sh -c 'col -bx | bat -l man -p'"
  ```

Comment: Opps, I didn't know it was $MANPAGER.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `nano` as a pager, you need to tell it to read from standard input:

```
MANPAGER='nano -' man printf
```

But the result won't be pretty, since `man` outputs formatting characters that `nano` will just present as-is instead of formatting the text.

And yes, this works for Vim too, and Vim has *some* support for this. See [`:h manpager.vim`](https://vimhelp.org/filetype.txt.html?#manpager.vim) for more details.

> Internally it seems the man just uses `sed` to send data

No, `man` doesn't use `sed` for anything. It does use `troff` for formatting the text.

---

> However since it is a binary, and the path to `/usr/bin` is in my path, there is a program called `pager` in linux as well, and i think it is what is default option for `$PAGER`,

If you're using Debian or some Debian derivative, that is the case. From [`man man`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/man.1.html):

```
-P pager, --pager=pager
      Specify which output pager to use.  By default, man uses pager, falling back to cat
      if pager is not found or is not executable.  This option  overrides  the  $MANPAGER
      environment  variable, which in turn overrides the $PAGER environment variable.  It
      is not used in conjunction with -f or -k.
```

This is not necessarily the case on other distributions (`pager`, which is just a symlink to some actual pager, might not even be present).

Comment: what is that `sed` that is showing in the error picture, My assumption was that `sed` is being used by the man here.

Comment: That I can't say. Seems to be some weird interaction between nano and less.